# how to pass parameter from nodejs to angularjs controller?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have this in nodejs

```
res.render('pages/dist/reset', {token:req.params.token});
```

and i can read it in reset.mustache

```
<body  ng-app="eyeApp" ng-controller="ResetController">  
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="layout-static">
                <div class="static-content-wrapper">
                    <div class="static-content">                                                                                  

                        <div id="wrap" ui-view class="mainview-animation animated"></div>

                         <!--wrap -->     
                    </div>
                    <footer role="contentinfo" ng-show="!layoutLoading" ng-cloak>   
                        <div class="clearfix">

                            <button class="pull-right btn btn-default toUp btn-sm hidden-print" back-to-top style="padding: 1px 10px;"><i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></button>
                        </div>   
                    </footer>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     {{token}}

    </body>
```

Controller from this file is ResetController.

ResetController:

```
 angular
      .module('telcoserv.eye.reset', [
        'telcoserv.core.services'      
      ])
      .controller('ResetController', ['$scope', '$theme','$http','$state','$window','$stateParams', function($scope,$theme,$http,$state,$window,$stateParams) {
        'use strict';          

        $scope.submit = function(){             
            alert('123');                  
            alert($scope.token);
    }

      }]);
```

alert($scope.token) is undefined.
when i say {{token}} in reset.mustache i can read value but $scope.token i can not read in resetController. Why??

Comment: angularjs doesn't know about other objects that were rendered. You should initialise it in the controller: `$scope.token = ...`

Comment: i don't want to initialize $scope.token. I want to pass parameter 'token' to resetController

Comment: how about receiving it with `$http.get('/pages/dist/reset').then((res) => {$scope.token = res.data;})`, or something similar? You can't _not_ initialise it to access it in your controller.

Answer (score 2):

```
$scope.submit = function(){             
    alert('123');                  
    alert($scope.token);

    $http({
        method:'',
        data: {json : data}
        url: ''
    }).then(function(response) {
        //Success response
    }, function(error) {
        //Failed response
    });
}
```

use `$http` to call your api. in `method` you can put `GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS` according to your api.

put your `URL`.

Put your request body in `data` as JSON only applicable for PUT, POST, DELETE.

Comment: I don't mean this. Maybe I did not correctly ask the question. Thank you for your time.

Comment: what's your question then ?

Comment: I will create again a question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to initialize some ways to achieve this and get that as parameter 
1. Create a constant service for getting token and inject it as a parameter in your controller . you can refer to this article how to create the constant service
https://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2014/01/14/angularjspart-9-values-and-constants/

2.On the route definition of the app , make use of the resolve in the route of the page using this controller and use of the same parameter and inject it as a dependency in your controller.